# Efficiently filling in spaces between two points of a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Given an n*n matrix represented as a string of length n*n, such as:

```
strMatrix = "......
             ......
             ......
             ......
             ......
             ......"
```

where n = 7, *what is the most efficient way to fill in the spaces between two indices*? For example, a function

```
fillSpaces(strMatrix, 0, 48)
```

would return:

```
            "*.....
             .*....
             ..*...
             ...*..
             ....*.
             .....*"
```

Comment: and question is?

Comment: @BakhromRakhmonov question is italicized

Comment: Show us what you tried, and I'll give you a hint on how to do this. :)

Comment: Or just prove that you did your research, and I'll tell you.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, this can be done in one for loop i.e O(n) complexity as you can fill in the diagonals on the go.

Here is the pseudo code for it:-

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  mat[i][i] = '*';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This only works on diagonals with a slope of 1, right? What if I needed to call fillSpaces(strMatrix, 0, 13), where the the diagonal is slanted heavily?

Comment: @RushilJoshi in that case you can see how many diagonals exists in that intervals like in 0 to 6 there will be 1 diagonal, 0 to 13 there will be 2 for n=7 and then you just mark the diagonals as *, you just want * to be present somewhere in between right